# Catch Exception from ActionFilter in ExceptionFilter in .net core c#

Tags: c#, .net, exception, action-filter

I have a `ActionFilter.cs` which throws exception in `OnActionExecuting` method as follows

```
if (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    token.Register(() => { throw new OperationCanceledException(token); });
}
```

[image]

I also have Global Exception Handler as `ExceptionFilter.cs` and its method `OnException` has the following code to handle the exception.

```
if (context.Exception is OperationCanceledException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Request was cancelled-------####@@@@@@");
}
```

and both are register in `Startup.cs` as

```
services.AddMvcCore().AddMvcOptions(x => {
                x.Filters.Add<ActionFilter>();
                x.Filters.Add<ExceptionFilter>();
})
```

Now After throwing the exception it should caught by ExceptionFilter but it's not working.Nothing is printed in console.How to catch this exception thrown from ActionFilter.cs?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Switch the filter registration round so the ExceptionFilter is registered first.

```
services.AddMvcCore().AddMvcOptions(x => {
    x.Filters.Add<ExceptionFilter>();
    x.Filters.Add<ActionFilter>();
})
```